# NavigationBarItem misplaced at first app start

Tags: swift

I have a strange issue with my NavigationBarItems. After first app start (when application was not running in background) the BarButton is misplaced (see Screenshot 1). The Button title should be "PDF".

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djWV9.png)

However, when i press the home button and open up the app again (from background), the position is correct (Screenshot 2).

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeC1k.png)

I can´t figure out what the problem is. I use a custom titleView for the navigation bar, which looks like that:

```
class TitleView : UIView {
    var titleLabel:UILabel!

    init(title:String) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 44))

        titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.normalFont(15)
        titleLabel.text = title.uppercaseString
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.primaryColor()
        self.addSubview(titleLabel)

        titleLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.edges.equalTo(self.snp_edges)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func setTitleView(title:String) {
        self.navigationItem.titleView = TitleView(title: title)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
```

And i initialize the navigationTitle and item in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
self.setTitleView("Tanzkarte")
let sendDanceCardButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "PDF", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(DanceCardController.sendDanceCard))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sendDanceCardButton
```

I didn`t find any solution for that problem in the internet and hope someone of you has a solution for it.

EDIT: the custom title view is not the issue. Even when I don´t use any title for the navigation bar, the button is misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

Your title view is initialized with an explicit width which probably exceeds the maximum width allowed by the navigation bar. Try to init it with zero size, and call `sizeToFit()` after initialization.

Comment: doesn´t seem like the titleView is the problem, since the issue persists when i dont init a titleView at all. (updated question)

Comment: In which callback method do you set up the right bar item?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I created an empty project, and just added the same "PDF" bar item in the navigation bar, and not see any glitch.

Comment: thats actually pretty strange, I have other projects where i initialize the navigation bar in the exact same way and it works. somehow in this project it is bugged. Don´t know what´s going on here.

Comment: Try to use interface builder to create the bar item. That should work.

Comment: when i just add the button in storyboard without connecting it to code or configure anything, it is also misplaced. This seems to be a bigger issue or bug